# $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \neq 0$ in $I \otimes_{R} I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $R = k[x,y]$ , $I = (x,y)$ , $k$ is a field.

I want to prove that :

1) $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \neq 0 $ in  $I \otimes_{R} I$

2) $x \otimes y - y \otimes x $ is a torsion element

My thoughts: to prove that $x \otimes y - y \otimes x \neq 0 $ in  $I \otimes_{R} I$ probably I should find a bilinear map $$\phi : I \times I \to R$$ such that $\phi(x,y) \neq \phi (y,x)$ , but which one?

Comment: Try a map to $\Lambda^2(R)$ instead.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542214

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume that $k$ is a commutative ring, put $t:=x\otimes y-y\otimes x$, and identify $k$ to $R/I$.

1) Using the $R$-bilinear map 
$$
I\times I\to k,\qquad(f,g)\mapsto
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(0,0),
$$ 
it is easy to see that $t$ is nonzero.

2) We have $xyt=0$.

Comment: very good answer!

Comment: O Sancta Simplicitas: bravo Pierre-Yves!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\phi: I\times I\rightarrow R/I$ to be the extension of product of $f:I\rightarrow R/I$ and $g: I\rightarrow R/I$. Here $f,g$ are given by extending
$$
f(x)\rightarrow 0, f(y)\rightarrow 1, f(1)\rightarrow 1; g(x)\rightarrow 1, g(y)\rightarrow 0, g(1)\rightarrow 1
$$ to all elements in $I$. 
Then we have
$$
\phi(x\otimes y)=f(x)g(y)=0, \phi(y\otimes x)=1
$$
So $x\otimes y\not=y\otimes x$.

(Thanks Watson for the update)

Comment: and for the torsion part ?

Comment: @WOLG: This should be easy, jut multiply $xy\otimes xy$.

Comment: Is your map well-defined? Because $\phi(y \otimes xy) = f(y)g(xy)=1 \cdot 0 = 0 \neq \phi(y^2 \otimes x) = f(y^2)g(x)=1$.

Comment: @Watson: I think this is a good point. The issue with $f,g$ is that $f,g$ are not really $R$-homomorphisms from $I$ to $R$, namely we do not want to have $f(xy)=x(f(y))=x!=y(f(x))=0$. They are only $R$-homomorphisms from $I$ to $R/I$ as an $R$-module like what Pierre did. This is a subtle point I should have made clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I still don't understand: even if we consider $\phi : I \times I \to R \to R/I$ (instead of just $\phi :  I \times I \to R$), we still have $$\phi(y,xy) = 0 + I \neq 1 + I = \phi(y^2,x) \in R/I.$$ Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "extending $f,g$" to all elements in $I$.

Comment: @Watson: In this case we have $\phi(y,xy)=x\phi(y,y)=0$, as the image is in $R/I$. Similarly $\phi(y^2,x)=y\phi(y,x)=0$.

Comment: Does finding such a map show that $x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x$ because this would imply that $0 \neq 1 = \phi(x \otimes y) - \phi(y \otimes x) = \phi(x\otimes y - y \otimes x)$ where the last equality comes from the fact $\phi$ is a homomorphism, is this reasoning right? I am having troubles rigorously justifying that finding such a map implies $x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x$. Thanks for the clarificatioN!